# Why ViewModel Binding Only Work on Debug and do not Work after deploy and Install on Device?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i'm creating a xamarin forms app and use bindingContext to bind viewmodel to view ... it's work fine on debug and visual studio android emulator but when 
i deploy and install it on Android device it's not work and show empty lable

This Is MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var model = new GoodViewModel();
        BindingContext = model;
    }
}
```

This is MainPage.xaml :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Good"
             x:Class="QuranProTst.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Good.Title}" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
           TextColor="BlueViolet"
               />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is GoodViewModel :

```
private readonly DataContext _db;
public GoodViewModel()
{
    _db = new DataContext();
    Good = _db.Goods.First(g => g.Id == 1);
    Goods = _db.Goods.ToList();
}

public List<Good> Goods { get; set; }
public Good Good { get; set; }
```

This is DataContext :

```
public class DataContext
    {
        public DataContext()
        {
            FillData();
        }
        public IList<Good> Goods { get; set; }  

        public void FillData()
        {
            var goodlist = new List<Good>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var good = new Good
                {
                    Id = i,
                    Title = $"GoodNumber{i}",
                    Price = i + 100

                };

                goodlist.Add(good);
            }

            Goods = goodlist;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the data coming from?  Are you sure that the data is being loaded properly on the device?

Comment: Yes .. DataContext is a Predefined list of Good Class

Comment: Have your `Good` model  implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface? If the code is same when you debug on the simulator and real device. The data probably is the cause.

Comment: The `GoodViewModel` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you want the view to be updated correctly when setting `Good` property